# How to make object while in for loop using node-mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I have **"for"** loop in a function and I want to make **1 object instead of many** to save draw calls. **Is there any way I could do that ?**  On my tests I have find out that I can't make var outside connection.query which would contain data from what query. So I can't even use global variable which is contained in that query. I am new on this so any help would be great.

**External file included in app.js**

```
    load_sent_mail: function(person_id, callback, socket) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE mail_sender = ' + person_id + '', function(err, mail_data) {
            if (!err) {
                for (var key in mail_data) {
                    var items_to_get_info = [];
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_1 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_1);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_2 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_2);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_3 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_3);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_4 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_4);
                    if (items_to_get_info.length) {
                        connection.query('SELECT `person_items`.`id`, `items`.`item_image`, `items`.`item_place` FROM `person_items` INNER JOIN `items` ON `person_items`.`item_id` = `items`.`item_id` WHERE `person_items`.`id`IN  (' + items_to_get_info.join(",") + ')', function(err, items_in_mail) {
                            if (!err) {
                                callback(null, items_in_mail);
                            } else {
                                console.log(err)
                            }
                        });
                    } {
                        //0 items
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        connection.release();
    });
}
```

**app.js**

```
mail.load_sent_mail(person_id,function(err,items_in_mail){
    socket.emit('incoming_mail', items_in_mail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, does this solve your problem:

```
load_sent_mail: function(person_id, callback, socket) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE mail_sender = ' + person_id + '', function(err, mail_data) {
            if (!err) {
                // Move this line before the loop
                var items_to_get_info = [];
                for (var key in mail_data) {
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_1 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_1);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_2 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_2);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_3 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_3);
                    if (mail_data[key].mail_spot_4 != 0) items_to_get_info.push(mail_data[key].mail_spot_4);
                }
                // Move this line after the loop
                if (items_to_get_info.length) {
                    connection.query('SELECT `person_items`.`id`, `items`.`item_image`, `items`.`item_place` FROM `person_items` INNER JOIN `items` ON `person_items`.`item_id` = `items`.`item_id` WHERE `person_items`.`id`IN  (' + items_to_get_info.join(",") + ')', function(err, items_in_mail) {
                        if (!err) {
                            callback(null, items_in_mail);
                        } else {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        })
        connection.release();
    });
}
```

I think I lost a bracket somewhere, but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: this query inside of for loop is necesary. 1st query gets info about what kind of items are inside of mail  mail_spot_1, mail_spot_2 ... Then for loop goes through all mails with info which it got from 1st query and places inside of 2nd. In your case it will take items only from last mail person got :)